# Missing addon in V2.78

Tags: add-on

I want to build a stair, according to a video of Youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5UrVrmErwQ), using "add mesh : building objects" addon.

I've noticed that the addon "add mesh : building objects" is missing from Blender 2.78.

Is there an option to download it from somewhere?

Comment: You can download some official addons from the old wiki, but why not use the latest versions?

Comment: Any version of Blender newer than 2.78, crashes on my windows 10 64bit pc...and I can't find the reason...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since 2.8 is changing every day there is no point for add-on creators to make their add-ons compatible with it, because the next update could make it incompatible again, which means many of them most likely won't be available until after 2.8 is officially released. For now though you could follow the tutorial in 2.79 and append it over to your 2.8 file.

Comment: The user states to be using 2.78, not 2.8

Comment: Totally misread, sorry for the irrelevant answer!

Comment: ROFL feelskekman